# Ruby Windows command-line globbing

Tags: ruby, windows

Ruby does a neat trick with the command-line on Windows - it does its own globbing (filename expansion).  This is because neither cmd.exe nor Powershell (Edit - WRONG, see below) does globbing like UNIX shells (bash, korn, etc.).

I have been browsing the source code `win32\win32.c` and I find it does magic things with quotes.  Windows cmd.exe only recognises double quotes, but Ruby strips out single quotes as well.

Say I'm writing a simple `grep` for Windows.  I want to pass a RE as the first argument, then a list of files:

```
pattern = ARGV.shift
puts pattern
puts ARGV
```

Here are some command-line experiments:

```
C:\>grep.rb u* u*
utf8file.txt
utf8file.txt

C:\>grep.rb "u*" u*
utf8file.txt
utf8file.txt

C:\>grep.rb 'u*' u*
u*
utf8file.txt
```

Wonderful!  Just want I want.  So what's the problem?

**Where is all this behaviour documented?**  What I DON'T want to do is to write code that depends on some quirky behaviour that I find gets trashed in the next release.  I want to make sure its a fully supported feature of the product, not some odd-ball side-effect that just happens to work.

Judging by related questions and their answers on Stack Overflow (and elsewhere), the feature seems to be little known.

Any ideas?

Edit:  following comments from @Patru I tried it on Powershell:

```
PS C:\> ruby grep.rb 'u*' u*
utf8file.txt
utf8file.txt

PS C:\> ruby grep.rb "u*" u*
utf8file.txt
utf8file.txt

PS C:\> ruby grep.rb ''u*'' u*
utf8file.txt
utf8file.txt

PS C:\> ruby grep.rb `'u*`' u*
u*
utf8file.txt
```

That last one cracked it.  "Escape" the single quotes using a backtick.  You could say that if you are using Powershell you get what you deserve. ;-)

Comment: Would thus [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954750/parsing-commandline-arguments-as-wildcards) helpful or [this](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/111252#257560) ?

Comment: At least part of the answer can be found in the third (unaccepted) answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/324278/how-to-make-windows-command-prompt-treat-single-quote-as-though-it-is-a-double-q). It basically states that on Windows argument handling is much more up to the application than in Unices. However there is no reference to the exact scope of what a Windows prompt is supposed to "do" itself (such as globbing and the like).

Comment: speculation:  does it follow the same rules as [Dir::glob](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Dir.html#M000629)?

Comment: According to the source code https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/edf2e9b7c75d2fff380f03c9ae279e53fe05ab59/win32/win32.c (search for "N.B."), strings in single quotes have been excluded from the globbing mechanism at least since 1999, so I'd say it's pretty reliable :-)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Yes, *Nobuyoshi Nakada* said the same [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/111252#257560).

Comment: This really might turn out like a small nightmare as `cmd.exe` seems to behave totally different (no expansions at all) from `powershell.exe` (supports the "regular" expansion). Some hints can be found in the answers to this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/460598/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-windows-cmd-shell-to-expand-wildcard-paths), but as `powershell` and `cmd` *both* seem to be preinstalled on Windows 7 you would have to support both! I have yet to figure out how far `ruby` can cover up this difference.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: that just about confirms what I found, but its hardly documentation.

Comment: @AShelly:  does it follow the same rules as Dir::glob?  Looks like it.  win32.c calls ruby_brace_glob which is in dir.c

Comment: @Patru: added Powershell examples, and a workaround.