# Using Ruby optparse to process list of files

Tags: ruby, optparse

Is it possible to process a list of files using Ruby's OptionParser, or does ARGV have to be parsed separately?

I am trying to parse command line parameters for a Ruby script running in Linux.  Currently my script is invoked using a style like: `./run.rb /dir/*` and I parse ARGV to get the list of files that it operates on.  However, now I have a couple of actions that I am switching between, so rather than edit the script I want to add a command line option.  So the script would be invoked as `./run.rb -a action -i /dir/*`.

When I was trying to get this working I ran into problems with only getting the first file that is in the directory.  "[Parsing command-line arguments as wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954750/parsing-commandline-arguments-as-wildcards)" explains that the reason is that the shell is expanding the list of files and that when OptionParser processes an Array it looks for comma separated values.  The answer also says:

> Because the * wildcard gets replaced with space delimited filenames
>   you'll have to post-process ARGV after OptionParser has run against
>   it, or programmatically glob the directory and build the list that
>   way. ARGV has all the files except the one picked up in the -a option
>   so, personally, I'd drop the -a option and let ARGV contain all the
>   files.

Is this correct that OptionParser doesn't have a way to processes space separated values as would be returned by shell expansion?  I haven't found anything so I'm think my interpretation is correct.  But I also think this would be a commonly used feature so I'm surprised that this is the case, hence the reason for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your script, but invoked with the options the other way round:

```
./run.rb -i /dir/* -a action
```

Assuming that `/dir/` contains two files, `foo` and `bar`, this will be expanded by the shell to:

```
./run.rb -i /dir/bar /dir/foo -a action
```

How would the script distinguish between the following?

1. two files being specified as the value of the `-i` option and the `-a` option being specified with `action` as the value (the intended case), and
2. *four* files being specified as the values of the `-i` action (`/dir/bar` and `/dir/foo` as before, plus `-a` and `action`)

The only way to do this is to insist the `-i` option is always last so there are no other options left, in which case you may as well do away with that option altogether and do what the answer you quote suggests.

Bear in mind that the shell does wildcard (and other) expansion and then splits the command on whitespace to create an array of strings, and does this *before* your script gets to see it, so this question is more to do with the shell than OptionParser (the same issue would affect any option parsing library in any language). I guess passing a list of files as an *option* to a command (rather than the main input) hasn’t come up enough to warrant changing shell behaviour or adding a feature to expand in a different way (at least I’m not aware of any such alternative expansion).

Answer (score 2):

It depends. File expansion can be ignored when you pass your argument like this

```
--list=Desktop/tour/*
```

in that case you can `Dir.glob` the files yourself.

On the other hand, OptionParser has the ability to handle lists of arguments:

```
opts.on("--list x,y,z", Array, "Example 'list' of arguments") do |list|
  options[:list] = list
end
```

You might combine all this with the other answers or look at advanced parsers like [trollop](http://trollop.rubyforge.org/).

Comment: thanks.  I think I'll stick with using ARGV after seeing the explanation in the other answer.  Still this looks like a good answer if someone really needed this functionality.

Comment: optParser doesn't allow me to separate filename with space. only comma. Is it possible to get all filenames into opt without using comma?